# Having Problems rendering .tiff image from filepath

Tags: .net, wpf, database, image

Ok here is the deal. I have to store a couple of images (tiff format) into a sql database.They have transparent background . I tired to store them, they got in perfectly . but when i retrieved them the background turned grey. That kinda defeats the entire purpose of my application. So i used another approach. i tried to save the filepath of the image into the DB. But i am having problems converting the path to a tiff image. Can anyone please help me render a tiff image from the filepath? Thanks all you guys in advance .

Comment: Not only is there no code, but you fail to even say what you use as your database (even if it's SQL Server, what version?). Nor do you say what method you save them in in the first case. It's not that the question won't be answered, it's that it **can't** be answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using tiff images, I recomend you to use libtiff. http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/help/basic-introduction-to-the-capabilities-of-the-library.aspx

The first portion of code show you how to load a tiff image from a file.

If you don't want to use for any reason, MSDN give you the code to load a tiff image in this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms748873.aspx